# ContextCompat.getColor crash in API 23 (Context.getColor not found)

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm using `ContextCompat.getColor` to get color resources and have backwards compatibility for deprecated methods like `Context`'s `getColor`.

E.g.:

`ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black)`

This works well everywhere I've used it so far, but I'm seeing a lot of problems in my app's crash logs like the following:

```
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getColor(I)I in class Landroid/content/Context; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.content.Context' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(ContextCompat.java:418)
   at com.myapp.MyView.method(MyView.kt:XXX)
```

Looking at the phones/Android versions, they are all in the Marshmallow family (6.0 – 6.1), and I added some logging around API detection, and can confirm that they are at API level 23.

In terms of manufacturers, they are Xiaomi, Lenovo, ZTE, and OPPO.

My solution so far is:

```
int color;
try {
    color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes);
} catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // log for a while, to catch if any other versions/devices have issues
        Timber.e(
                e,
                "Couldn't use getColor in API level %s (%s)",
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT,
                Build.VERSION.RELEASE
        );
    }
    color = context.getResources().getColor(colorRes);
}
// Now I know color has a value :D
```

This works fine but it's far from ideal, as I was hoping to be able to use `ContextCompat` transparently and forget about this.

I've tried appcompat versions `27.1.0` and `28.0.0`. Has anyone come across this problem? Is there a better way to deal with it?

Comment: Personally I've never seen this. Makes me wonder if something like proguard is stripping out ContextCompat methods it shouldn't.

Comment: @BenP. interesting point, thanks for bringing it up... I AM using Proguard, but I doubt it's related, as this ONLY happens for a particular Android version, and certain manufacturers.

Comment: whats your support library version?

Comment: @stallianz: I'm using `27.1.0`

Comment: I don't see that error, and I'm using 27.1.1. try it once.

Comment: @stallianz what device/Android version are you testing on?

Comment: I use it on variety of devices, yes of course on 6.0 - 6.1 as well and it is working fine.

Comment: @stallianz, thanks again! Is any of those devices one of the listed above? I've never seen it fail with Motorola, Samsung, LG, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`ContextCompat.getColor()` is the part of the Support V4 Library.

```
ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.my_color)
```

You need to add the **Support V4 library** by adding the following dependencies in your app build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. However, as I say on the question, this is not a problem of `ContextCompat.getColor` not being found, but of the underlying implementation not finding `getColor` in the `Context` object in some specific cases

Comment: Where you are writing this code, in Fragment or in Activity class?

Comment: This is in a custom view, which is inside an Activity. I'm not using Fragments at all

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try to replace **context**  with **YourActivity.this**. The error you have mentioned above is something related to context object you are passing.

Comment: Can you explain why do you think this is the case? Again, this only happens in Android M and for certain vendors... Other versions of Android on those vendors, and M in other vendors work just fine.